# Javascript Vars in onclick

Tags: javascript, html, random, download, onclick

**So,pretty much** I've run into a problem with my script.
I'm trying to make a download script (memory only,so no downloading using HTML/PHP that would cost servers to load more than I want).
What I've done is gotten a script off of here ([credit Matěj Pokorný](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)).
The point is to download a txt file with a random number,it is assigned a var "x",
this x is defined in the same script.
x is defined as a random number (1-10 * 1000 FLOORED)
so example it would be 1234.txt when it downloaded.
Unfortunately I have no idea how to define variables in onclick,would someone willing to fix this up for me?
I tried moving the variable around and putting the 's around the txt and the whole thing and everything but to no avail.
I'm SOO sorry how stupid this is but maybe my crazy stupid question could help someone else.

Script on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Xevion/btpmweb9/1/

HTML

```
    <h1>Z</h1>
<p>Z</p>
<button onclick="download(x'.txt', 'Hello world!');" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Download</button>
```

Javascript

```
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);function download(filename, text) {
var pom = document.createElement('a');

pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

if (document.createEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    pom.dispatchEvent(event);
}
else {
    pom.click();
}
```

Comment: Do everything inside your function.  Don't try to pass `x'.txt'` into it.

Comment: @Teepeemm I'm kinda hoping that I could do externally but,is there no other option? No way to mention variables and combine a part of text within a variable? (foo= x+(.txt) x=?)

Answer (score 0):

`x'.txt'` is not a valid type and cannot be parsed by the JS engine. You want to perform string concatenation instead. Replace with `x+'.txt'` inside your function call.

To grasp the mistake, try this in the console:

```
var x = "something";

'.txt'; // 'txt'
x; // 'something'
x'.txt'; // SyntaxError: Unexpected string
x+'.txt'; // 'something.txt'
```

The script should also be included before the `button` markup, or at least `x` must have been defined before the `onclick` function is parsed. A small step to rectify the situation could be to add this anywhere above `button`:

```
<script>var x;</script>
```

By the time you click the button, the original script will have run and `x` will have taken its value.

Comment: You forgot the "." in ".txt".

Comment: @Teepeemm I can adjust my code to fit this. the var = x thing was added,its not NEEDED. I just  want to make this externally changeable,so I don't have to change everything and make it internal.

Comment: @Teepeemm True, it depends on the script's position; it would have to be included before the button markup.

Comment: @Xevion you are evaluating `x` before it is assigned a value. `x` should be assigned before `y`.